# why is the following not writing array content to file

Tags: c, file-io

i have a bit array with this structure

```
bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

I tried to write it to a file as

```
FILE * f; 
        f = fopen("D:\\test_bf\\bf_file", "a+b"); 
        if (f != NULL)  
        {               
            fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(bit_table_), 1, f); 
            fclose(f);              

        } 
        else 
        { 
            std::cout<<"File could not be opend.";
            printf("\tError  %d\t\t%s", errno,strerror(errno));
        }
```

writing is successful but size of the file  is 0kb and its content is empty. I expect to have a file size in MBs.

I have used this same code in another program and works as intended.

What is wrong with it?

EDIT:

Here is how i actually used the above code in a function

```
void write_to_file(unsigned char bit_table_[][COLUMNS])
   {


         FILE * f; 
        f = fopen("D:\\test_bf\\chunk_bf_file.txt", "a+b"); 
        if (f != NULL)  
        { 

            fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(bit_table_), 1, f); 
            fclose(f); 


        } 
        else 
        { 
            std::cout<<"File could not be opend.";
            printf("\tError  %d\t\t%s", errno,strerror(errno));
        }


   }
```

Here is how it is called:

```
write_to_file(bit_table_);
```

Here is its declaration:

```
static unsigned char    bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

Comment: Did you forget the extension?

Comment: This begs the question, what are the values of `ROWS` and `COLUMNS`?

Comment: Did you check the return value from fwrite? And errno if fwrite indicates an error? That will most likely give you the answer.

Comment: @MrLister: they are very large, like **24x1048576**. I have updated my post

Comment: OK, but `bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS]` is NOT the same as `bit_table_[][CHUNK_COLUMNS]`! What is `sizeof(bit_table_)` inside the function?

Comment: @MrLister: it is supposed to be 24x1048576 but it is just 4 and when i used sizeof(*bit_table) it writes only 1024 kb which is still not write

Comment: Yes. What you should do is pass the original size `ROW*COLUMNS` to the function and use that instead of trying to compute it with `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(bit_table_), 1, f);
```

to

```
  fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(bit_table_[0][0]), ROWS*COLUMNS, f);
```

and you should be ok

Comment: thanks! This worked but i needed to change it to **fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(bit_table_[0][0]), ROWS*COLUMNS, f);**

Answer (score 1):

How did you declare `bit_table_`? If you used `malloc()` then `sizeof(bit_table)` will only return the size of the pointer, not the size of your array.

Edit: Your `write_to_file` function should look as `write_to_file(unsigned char* bit_table_, int rows, int columns)`. Your `fwrite` call should then look something like `fwrite(bit_table_, sizeof(unsigned char), rows*columns, f)`.

Comment: The OP says it's `bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS]`, so I assume that's what it is. But even it it were a pointer, the `fwrite` would still output 4 bytes (or whatever the size of a pointer).

Comment: You are almost certainly right. However the information should be supplied by the OP for clarity.